# Trying to get file with max lines to print with lines number

Tags: linux, bash, shell

So i've been goofing with this since last night and I can get a lot of things to happen just not what I want.

I need a code to find the file with the most lines in a directory and then print the name of the file and the number of lines that file has.

I can get the entire directory's lines to print but can't seem to narrow the field so to speak.

Any help for a fool of a learner?

```
wc -l $1/* 2>/dev/null
   | grep -v ' total$'
   | sort -n -k1
   | tail -1l
```

After some pro help in another question, this is where I got to, but it returns them all, and doesn't print their line counts.

Comment: Can you show us what you've tried so far?

Comment: btw, I just tried your solution `wc -l $1/* 2>/dev/null | grep -v 'total$' | sort -n -k1   | tail -1l` and it works. I don't understand what are you making wrong.

Comment: Your command line works for me (on CentOS 6), in that I get a single line result with the number of lines and the name of the file.  Which Linux distribution are you running?

Comment: what shell and shell version are you using too?

Comment: I'm using Ubuntu, newest Ver with the standard terminal

Comment: I guess i'm trying to get it to print with what would need to be an echo.  so when it prints it says something like "The file [file] has the maximum number of lines {43 lines)"

So i'd need to echo 'The file [wc -lsomething] to start, i'd assume?

Comment: If you are trying to run the code as shown, you have a single call to `wc` terminated by a newline, so it runs. The following lines look like syntax errors, since you can't start a pipeline with a pipe. Move the pipe characters so that they end each line; a line that ends with a pipe is implicitly continued since another command is expected.

Answer (score 1):

Following awk command should do the job for you and you can avoid all redundant piped commands:

```
wc -l $1/* | awk '$2 != "total"{if($1>max){max=$1;fn=$2}} END{print max, fn}'
```

**UPDATE:** To avoid last line of wc's output this might be better awk command:

```
wc -l $1/* | awk '{arr[cnt++]=$0} END {for (i=0; i<length(arr)-1; i++) 
                  {split(arr[i], a, " "); if(a[1]>max) {max=a[1]; fn=a[2]}} print max, fn}'
```

Comment: your solution will not work given the following directory: `a b c d total` where total has more lines than all the other files, it will only output an empty line.

Comment: Now it does not report a file named `total` that has the most number of lines

Comment: @1_CR: Actually it does support file named "total". Have you tried the command yourself?

Comment: @anubhava, i ran it on RHEL: `wc -l  l.txt test.t total 0 l.txt
 5 test.t
 7 total
12 total
wc -l  l.txt test.t total | awk '$2 != "total"{if($1>max){max=$1;fn=$2}} END{print max, fn}'
5 test.t`

Comment: @1_CR: That is not the solution I wrote :) Pay special attention to `wc -l $1/*` which will always put `/` before every filename.

Comment: @anubhava, ah I see. So if the files are in current dir, stick a `./` in front of them? Bit dicey but I guess it should be ok since the OP's requirement states a directory. +1

Comment: @1_CR: Yes that's right. Dicey yes but it is OP's command that starts with `wc -l $1/*` I just suggested a way to avoid all subsequent piped commands with a simple awk

Answer (score 0):

you can try:

```
wc -l $1/* | grep -v total | sort -g | tail -1
```

actually to avoid the grep that would also remove files containing "total":

```
for f in $1/*; do wc -l $f; done | sort -g | tail -1
```

or even better, as suggested in comments:

```
wc -l $1/* | sort -rg | sed -n '2p'
```

you can even make it a function:

```
function get_biggest_file() {
    wc -l $* | sort -rg | sed -n '2p'
}

% ls -l
...  0 Jun 12 17:33 a
...  0 Jun 12 17:33 b
...  0 Jun 12 17:33 c
...  0 Jun 12 17:33 d
... 25 Jun 12 17:33 total
% get_biggest_file ./*
5 total
```

EDIT2: using the function I gave, you can simply output what you need as follows:

```
get_biggest $1/* | awk '{print "The file \"" $2 "\" has the maximum number of lines: " $1}'
```

EDIT: if you tried to write the function as you've written it in the question, you should add line continuation character at the end, as follows, or your shell will think you're trying to issue 4 commands:

```
wc -l $1/* 2>/dev/null \
   | grep -v ' total$' \
   | sort -n -k1 \
   | tail -1l
```

Comment: Your second way would require invoking `wc` once for every file though. How about this &ndash; `wc -l $1/* | sort -rg | sed -n '2p'`?